Is there a way to scale nv12 surface decoded by dxva?
I have the surfaces decoded by dxva, whose format is nv12. I want to process the picture on GPU, just scale it, and output a different size picture with the same output format (nv12).
I tried StretchRect, but it seems not to work to scale; it can only do layout only, so is there any way to be ok?
